# Multiple webpack vendor bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

Tried creating two vendor bundles in webpack and this error happened when I ran the final scripts on server:

```
vendor1.369f8f5….js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at t (vendor1.369f8f5….js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.369f8f5….js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.369f8f5….js:1)
    at t (vendor1.369f8f5….js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.369f8f5….js:6)
    at t (vendor1.369f8f5….js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (vendor1.369f8f5….js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (vendor2.369f8f5….js:1)
    at main.369f8f5….js:1
```

This is my webpack.config:

```
  entry: {
    /* Material Design Lite (https://getmdl.io) */
    // '!!style-loader!css-loader!react-mdl/extra/material.min.css',
    // 'react-mdl/extra/material.min.js',
    /* The main entry point of your JavaScript application */
    main:'./main.js',
    vendor1:['react','router','mixpanel-browser','react-dom','preact','preact-compat'],
    vendor2:['core-js','fastclick','whatwg-fetch','axios',],
    // vendor3:['core-js'],
    // vendor4:['mixpanel-browser'],
  },
```

......

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "vendor1",
  chunks:['main'],
  minChunks:Infinity,
}),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "vendor2",
  chunks:['main'],
  minChunks:Infinity,
}),
```

I could successfully create these three bundles but they didn't work when running on server.
[image]

It's perfectly fine when I am only having one vendor and one main bundle. However I have failing to create a second vendor bundle for smaller file size. Have searched around solutions online but none of it worked. Maybe it has to do with my syntax?

Comment: Was any solution found?

Comment: @ArtemSky nope. i had to go with two bundles in the end, can't split more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know my solution will work or not...

Will you try using single `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` for both `vendor1` and `vendor2`.

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ["vendor1","vendor2"],
  chunks:['main'],
  minChunks:Infinity,
}),
```

Comment: If i did it this way, the main bundle will not exclude vendor modules. So it will not achieve the purpose of reducing file size with duplicate modules across bundles. Thanks though :)  i have literally tried all different combos for this